# Добавление текста в textBox1 по повторному нажатию кнопки

Tags: c++-cli

Есть кнопка, код которой записывает путь выбранного пользователем файла в textBox1.
Как сделать так, что бы при повторном добавлении файла (другого) путь записывался в строке ниже и т.д. до установленного ограничения?

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{
    if (openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
    {
        textBox1->Text = openFileDialog1->FileName;
    }
    try
    {
    }
    catch (Exception ^ e)
    {
        MessageBox::Show(this, "Файл не был открыт", "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил заменой оператора "=" на "+="